# Can I transfer Kerbonauts from a capsule to Hitchhiker Storage Container without taking an EVA?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've been constructing a space station, and up to this point, I've been using autonomous launch vehicles to put unmanned sections into orbit.  But now it's time to have a permanent presence in orbit.

I've just docked my first crew transfer vehicle to the station hub, and now I want to transfer the crew to one of the Hitchhiker pods, but they don't want to seem to go through the docking ports I conveniently placed.

How can I move them onto the station without taking them on an EVA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of the latest version (.18), the ability to transfer crew via docking ports has not been implemented.  Fuel can be transferred without a problem, but crew, unfortunately, require EVA to populate the habitation modules.

Answer (score 6):

It **is** now possible to transfer crew members without EVA between docked ships.

The KSP wiki has a section explaining how at the bottom of the [Crew](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Crew#Crew_transfer) page:

> ... in case of transfer option, we can click on an another cabin with free seat in the same craft *or a docked together group* ...

<strike>Not sure which version this was added</strike>, but the [screenshot on the wiki](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/File:Crew_Transfer_Menu.jpg) is dated October 2014.

EDIT:

This was added in v0.25 - [see the release notes on the wiki](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/0.25#Crew_Transfer) that has a section stating:

> **Crew Transfer**
>
> Kerbals in the same vessel don't need a spacesuit anymore to switch seats. Just click the crew hatch and select Transfer to tell them to go sit somewhere else.

Comment: That might be with a mod. I don't think that's vanilla. I haven't played Kerbal for a little bit though.

Comment: @RobertRose: It is vanilla ksp as of v0.25

Answer (score 4):

While there's no *stock* way to do it as far as 0.20.1, there's a fan-made plugin that implements that functionality and more:

http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/showthread.php/24636-0-20-Kerbal-Crew-Manifest-v0-5-3-0-Released!-Create-Edit-Remove-Kerbals

It also lets you pre-populate the Hitchhiker pods when you launch them, if you so desire.

Edit: still true as of 0.24